# Can someone explain Math.random() and width/height used together to me?

Tags: java, swing, random, components, containers

For example, i am trying to write a code about drawing figures. x and y position have to be initialized so that the whole figure is drawn in the window:

```
int x = (int) (width * Math.random() * 0.75);
int y = (int) (heigth * Math.random() * 0.75);
```

The size of the figure should not be larger than 1/8 of the width of the window:

```
int figureWidth = (int)(x * 0.29);
int figureHeight = (int)(y * 0.29);
```

Why multiply the width with Math.random() and 0.75? where does 0.75 and 0.29 come from?
In what contexts would getWidth()/getHeight() be considered ? Can someone point the way to some resources to help me learn more or explain here? Thanks.

Comment: its wrong. need to be 1.0/8.0 instead of 0.75*0.29

Comment: You may want to read Math.random() javadoc first. It returns fraction between 0 and 1. So I think x and is meant to not exceed width and height respectively. 0.75 and 0.29 is just a percentage I think, so that the figure does not fill the whole window.

Comment: do you mean: int figureWidth = (int)(width * Math.random() * 0.125); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.random() returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. So according to the code,  x and y are taken at random and less than the 75% of the window's size, then further they are taken down to 29% to give figureWidth and figureHeight. 
According to me all this wrong, i think you want the random coordinate on the screen as x and y, size as figureWidth and figureHeight.

So the size should be calculated as

```
int figureWidth = (int)(width * 0.29);
int figureHeight = (int)(height * 0.29);
```

But it will be 29% of the screen, for 25% use 0.25 instead of 0.29.

Comment: but why multiply width * Math.random()? / int width = drawPanel.getWidth()

Comment: exactly! - so 0.29 is just a random number like 35% or 33 %? because i thought that 0.29 has something to do with the 1/8 of the width of the window?!

Comment: here it's not a random, it's static.